# How can we create and calculate a ([Due Date]- [Today])/7 column in SP 2010?

Tags: 2010, calculated-column

How can we calculate `([Due Date]- [Today])/7` column that updates daily as value of Today changes and lets us calculate weeks left for due date ? Could create `([Due Date]- Today() )/7` and it worked fine but it value of `Today()` in this is not dyanmic and changes only when we edit an existing entry or create a new one .

Any ideas as how to achieve display of weeks left for due date dynamically ?

Comment: Create a workflow to update the Today field daily. I am going to try that.

Answer (score 1):

Did you google "dynamic value of today sharepoint" ? You can see that this topic has been discussed again and again, in MOSS and SP2010.

There is a workflow with loop "solution" :
https://sites.google.com/site/sharepointhill/tutorials/mssp/sp-dynamic-today-date

Or a XSLT "Solution" :
https://sharepointapplied.wordpress.com/2009/04/23/useless-calculated-column-today-trick-xsl-today-to-the-rescue/

Or you may want to add some custom code or timer jobs that update each element of the targeted list every X minutes ....

Good Luck !

Comment: fyi - your 2nd hyperlink above has gone stale

Comment: here's the new location for the [XSLT solution](https://sharepointapplied.wordpress.com/2009/04/23/useless-calculated-column-today-trick-xsl-today-to-the-rescue/)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an article a while back about the different methods for creating a CountDown on a list view, which is essentially what you're looking for:

*Warning: This also mentions our own product as a possible solution*

[How to create a Countdown in a SharePoint list](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2011/05/how-to-create-a-countdown-in-a-sharepoint-list/)

Here is a summary of the options:

- **JavaScript**: Use a Content Editor Web Part.
- **Designer**: Create a custom view in SharePoint Designer.
- **Code**: Make your own custom field type from scratch.
- **SharePoint Highlighter**: Buy our product (notably this doesn't currently support Weeks, just Days and/or Months)

More specifically, I also wrote a (similarly product plugging) article on using [Today] in a list view:

[How to use [Today] in a SharePoint list](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2011/05/how-use-today-in-a-sharepoint-list/)

This article gives more background on why [Today] doesn't work:

> Unfortunately because of the much larger amount of information
>   SharePoint has to pass back and forth, it takes a different approach
>   to updating the data items. It will only update calculated values when
>   the related item is added or edited.
>
> Consider SharePoint as an overworked secretary; if you ask for a file
>   to be updated they’ll find it in the filing cabinet, update the
>   information, and correct anything else that’s awry on the paperwork
>   while they’re there. If you ask for all the files for people named
>   “Smith” to be put on your desk, unless you specifically say “And
>   update the information on every single one while you’re at it”, it’s
>   not likely they’ll do the extra work for no reason.

It also received the following rave review from the venerable [Mike Walsh himself](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointcustomization/thread/e2c8876e-b65d-491b-b605-42ffc7d79389/):

> I also didn't think much of the way the advert section was written. Information it wasn't - overdone marketing it was.