# configuring status list using date column, if greater than [date column] status goes red

Tags: 2010, list

I am using a status list that is pulling from another sharepoint list, I would like to use a date column labeled "Due Date" and tell the indicator to turn red when the "Due Date" has passed...

This is in sharepoint 2010:

I have selected - Percentage of list items in the view where:

1. Due Date
2. is greater than
3. Current date? <--- this is the field where I cannot figure out how to make this work, what formula text am i putting in there?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I recommend looking at these questions: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/10217/1529 http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12341/how-can-i-display-a-message-on-a-list-item-when-within-x-days-of-a-date http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/45951/how-can-we-create-and-calculate-a-due-date-today-7-column-in-sp-2010

Answer (score 1):

Where are you doing this?  In SPD?  SharePoint has a constant [Today] which should provide what you need.

Comment: was doing this in sharepoint, just tried it...thx!